# PSEUDO CODE & Python for finding the greatest, second greatest, and least number

Tags: python, pseudocode

I am a student and for a task I have to write code for a task in both python and pseudocode. The task has been done but I don't really like ending lines of code which compares variables to find the greatest, 2nd greatest and least value. I am using if statements but was wondering if there was a better way to do this. I know of the sort function, and that can be used in case of python but what about pseudocode.

To see the code: Lines[72:92] http://pastebin.com/MTnifkek

To see the python code: http://pastebin.com/fvqqstXW

In python it's the same but instead I use nested ifs.
As you may notice, this was my first time, and apologies on any errors.
I tried think but other than nesting ifs I was blank.
I was thinking a for loop:

```
for count in charity_value:
if count > max:
max == count
elif count < min:
min == count
```

Though how would I find the middle value ?

Comment: Put the data in a list, sort the list and take the appropriate values from the sorted list.

Comment: `==` is equality test, not assignment.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This means *don't post your code on other websites*.

Comment: you shall try out min(), max() and numpy.median() functions.

Comment: @MattDMO I am not having any real issue with the code in execution in python. For the task I also have to write the code in Pseudo and just wanted something better than 'bad and inefficient' multiple if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how you do it in pseudocode. Just watch out for the `==` and `=`. It's not the same, the first one is for equality testing and the other is assignment.

In python you might want to use `max(charity_value)` as well as `min(charity_value)`